# Validation Rule not displaying under the field definition

Tags: validation, customization

When I check the validation rules related to an opportunity, I see that a field is referenced in the validation rule, when I go to the actual field the validation rule section displays nothing. Is this a known issue / do all the orgs have the same setting?

Please clarify

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation Rules are only shown when you select to show the error on the field. If you are just referencing the field in your validation rule, it doesn't show in the related list. Try changing the Validation Rule to show error on the field.